# Rails/SQL : group by variant and sum quantities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, rails-activerecord

```
class Order
  has_many :lines
end

class Line
  belongs_to :variant
end

class Variant
end
```

A `Line` has a column `quantity`.

How can I group and find all variants and corresponding quantities in an `order`.

Example:

```
Line 1:
  quantity: 2
  variant_id: 5
  order_id: 1
Line 2
  quantity: 3
  variant_id: 6
  order_id: 1
Line 3
  quantity: 3
  variant_id: 5
  order_id: 1
```

The result should be:

```
{ 5 => 5, 6 => 3 }
```

The keys are `variant_id` and values are `sum(quantity)' for the lines related to the variant.

I tried:

```
@order.lines.group('variant_id').count
```

But how to get the sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
@order.lines.group('variant_id').sum(:quantity)
```

Comment: It workd with sum(:quantity) and not count(:quantity) Thank you.

Comment: Funny, just exactly when i noticed that :)